# Rails 2 + Spree 0.11.0: How do routes work when there are so many routes files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a legacy Rails app that uses a really old version of Spree (spree (0.11.0)) and I have to move a nested resource one level up.

Ex: The path right now is: `/boutique/shop/gourmet-specialties/blah`, while I need to change it to `/boutique/shop/blah`, without the gourmet-specialties part.

I located the partial where these links are generated:

```
    <%- if current_taxon && current_taxon.root == taxonomy.root -%>
      <%- taxonomy.root.children.each do |taxon| -%>
        <%- unless taxon_preview(taxon).empty? -%>
        <li<%= ' class="current"' if current_taxon and ([current_taxon] + current_taxon.ancestors).include?(taxon) %>>
          <%= link_to taxon.name, seo_url(taxon), :title => taxon.name %>
        </li>
        <%- end -%>
      <%- end -%>
    <%- end -%>
```

Can anyone guide me on how to begin or how routes work in Spree so that I can go about it on my own? There are so many routes files and I don't know how to interact with each other. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes should be specified in config/routes.rb

Here's where they're specified in Spree 0.11.0:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v0.11.0/config/routes.rb

Modern versions of Spree are [mountable Rails engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) which will mount some of its own routes underneath your applications routes.  However, you're dealing with the rails 2 version which injects its routes a little differently.  You're dealing with a very old version of Spree, so many of the resources you find on the internet will pertain to more modern versions of Spree (Rails 3.0+).

Your easiest bet will be to figure out where 'gourmet-specialties' is coming from and remove it.  If it's coming from the taxonomy tree, try recategorizing it under the root taxon.

Comment: I think you're on to something. It does seem Taxonomy related from the log, but the issue is that I can't find out how to edit the routes file and controller when they are embedded into the spree gem itself. Do you know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: ` If it's coming from the taxonomy tree, try recategorizing it under the root taxon.` I think this is the answer I'm looking for instead of screwing around with the routes. How would I recategorize it so that the `gourmet-specialties` is removed and so that I can still loop through them?

Comment: Could I do this in the Admin section? I went to `/admin` and clicked on `Categories` and found the Gourmet Specialties category, with all the products listed under it

Comment: @gmacdougall, is it possible to have resourceful routing in Spree. how to do that ?